# Automated Deployment not working

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm following the guide [here](http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/), to automate the deployment of my bitbucket repo.

However, though the POST hook seems to work, and the log file is created - no files are pulled. Comments in the attached link discuss permissions as being a possible issue.

I've done a few chown's, but with no luck.

Any suggestions on how to fix? Is this something only my hosting company can solve? What do I ask them to change?

Thanks.

Comment: I did not read that blog post, but if git pull is the issue did you try doing a git pull manually as the user which is used by that script and see if any errors show up?

Comment: Hi, I did - using my default user, and all is well. Comments in that post basically said that maybe the server is using another user (apache or something) when running the script as a 'call', and that user is the issue? Don't really understand that too well.. and without root, not sure what I can do.    Thanks!

Comment: With no root access I believe you are on shared/managed hosting. So your options are probably limited. Do the logs have any info on the output of the `git pull` command? Just to find the root cause you can try making your project directory world writable (666) and see if that works. If it does then you know its the permissions issue. But be sure to revert the permissions after the experiment. A couple of comments on that post provide links to scripts which do `sudo`. Those might work for you if your `default user` has sudo permissions.

Comment: im on shared hosting, with no sudo :( but on my previous shared host, this worked.. so it must be possible - I'll write to them and see what we can do. Thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify the 666 chmod? for the whole repo recursive?

Comment: 777 is a better option than 666 for this experiment. Set that permission to your project dir where all the deployment is happening and see if it works. If it does then the problem is that whatever user the php script is running in is currently not have permission which I believe has a few solutions, the easiest one being give permission to that user. But that might open up several security bugs.

Comment: It kinda worked when I changed everything to 777 (was the wrong commit that got pulled, but thats another issue). Now, something weird happed, everything is owned by group 99 and I cant change the permissions.    Anyhow, at least the issue is narrowed done to permissions - many thanks!!!

Comment: lastly (for others reference), by running this code: <? print "hello world<p>\n"; system("id"); ?> I got this output = uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody) context=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0 whereas, on my other working server, the owner was my account user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks to be a permissions issue.

by running this code:

```
<? print "hello world<p>\n"; system("id"); ?>
```

I got this output =

```
uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody) context=system_u:system_r:initrc_t:s0
```

whereas, on my other working server, the owner was my account user account.

Not sure how to actually resolve that - but at least the root cause is known.

EDIT: issue was solved by having the hosting company enable Suexec. This allows the PHP scripts to run under my ID, not that of nobody.

Comment: Makes sense. Your hosting provider is running your server process as that user (uid=99). You can try setting the ownership of the deployment directory to "your-user-account:99" and giving group write permissions(775). This assumes only you are the member of that group(gid=99). Check with the provider. If you cannot do stuff like this ask if your provider would do it for you. The directory creation is a one time thing. Check if your script will always run under uid=99 and gid=99 or if it changes dynamically. But this automation is probably not a good solution for such a restrictive environment.

Comment: thanks for the comments Brahmana, you've been great! One extra thing: someone is the original blog comments wrote "you don't need to modfiy the script at all, but you need only to add the ssh public key for the user running apache/nginx to bitbucket"  .... do you know how I would do that myself? I'm not really sure what they mean. I simple created my normal ssh key using ssh-keygen. Do they mean, I'd need to do that as the 'nobody' user? If so, how could I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Read that comment but I am not sure if you can use it in your environment. He "probably" means you create a ssh key for that user (uid=99) and put it in that users home dir at ~/.ssh/id_rsa. I am not sure if he means different.

Comment: ok, cheers. Either way, I cannot see or create a folder for nobody anyhow :) Tomorrow the support guys are there - hopefully they'll suggest a solution. Thanks again - have a good end to your weekend!